# Replacing png files in blog from image folder

Tags: unix, sed, path, markdown, rendering

I have created git blog for my projects.And i was trying to replace images in Ipython notebook from a folder but unable to map to correct folder.

This is the path of my image folder in computer
IMG_PATH="/e/Github/${GH_USER}github.io/images

Sed command to replace image in blog from folder(script)

**sed -i .bak "s:[png](:[png](/images/:" $POST_NAME**

It is rendered in my ipython markdown file as

*(Linear_model_files/Linear_model_8_0.png)*

*instead of /images/Linear_model_files/Linear_model_8_0.png*

How i change sed command to point to right image source.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwrRY.png)